# Rstudio fails to connect to SSL enabled postgresql server on windows machine

Tags: windows, postgresql, rstudio

I am facing a problem while connecting with a SSL enabled PostgreSQL server from Windows. I am getting the following error:

> Error :
>   Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, …) :
>   RS-DBI driver: (could not connect ip:80 on dbname "all": sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in.

Commands I have used :

```
install.packages(“RPostgreSQL”)
install.packages(“rstudioapi”)
require(“RPostgreSQL”)
require(“rstudioapi”)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
pg_dsn = paste0(
'dbname=', "all", ' ',
'sslmode=require')

con <- dbConnect(drv,
dbname = pg_dsn,
host = "ip",
port = 80,
user = "abcd",
password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a PostgreSQL client shared library (`libpq.dll`) that was built with SSL support.

Comment: This library isn't available when we try to install it with in the rtsudio package .

Comment: What client does Rstudio use?

Comment: RStudio Desktop Version 1.1.463

Comment: Sorry; I wanted to say "what *PostgreSQL* client does it use"?

Comment: RPostgreSQL version 0.6-2.